# Making an "Invisible Screen" Is It Possible?

Tags: optics

I just want to know, if you used a material like "Vantablack" in conjunction with a MetaMaterial that bends light from any direction, around an object Are we able to make an "Invisibility Cloak" or, "Invisibility Screen"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, in theory this is possible. We have been able to create metamaterials that have a negative refractive index. However these metamaterials do not work yet for the visible wavelengths yet. However microwave and infrared wavelengths have been achieved (radar and telecom optics).

As technology progresses, visible wavelengths should also become possible.

A negative refractive index would allow you to bend light around an object making it seem like it's not there. However this is not as trivial as people make it out to be and would require a lot of engineering still.

So in theory, yes it's possible, in practice it might be harder, maybe even only be possible for small wavelength windows.

You can read some about it here, [Some news article that's not too technical](http://theconversation.com/beyond-invisibility-engineering-light-with-metamaterials-54632), [review paper (open access)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369702106715735) and [A book about the topic.](https://www-sciencedirect-com.kuleuven.ezproxy.kuleuven.be/science/article/pii/S0079663807510012)

[Article available online, where they cloak an object from microwave wavelengths.](http://www.wfsj.org/course/docs/Cloack_Schurig-10-20-06.pdf)

Comment: I think it would be possible to create a "sphere" around an object rendering it invisible using metamaterials and something like vantablack? as well as this: https://www.livescience.com/51925-magnetic-wormhole-created.html ?

Comment: @Inventor.ruff okay? so? could you please be more clear about what your question is?